# Set the visibility of a column that has been grouped (single column)

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid

I am grouping data in a grid by two different columns.

One of the columns needs to be retained as visible and the other needs to be removed from the grid.

I have set "ShowGroupedColumns" to false as it automatically handles the column chooser etc.

But I cant seem to figure out how to make the one I want to retain visible.

Is there any way, with ShowGroupedColumns set to false that I can have it grouped by column and have the column in the grid too?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same problem have been already discussed in [DevExpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center): 
[Display individual columns, even if they are grouped](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q364806.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, I searched and searched and did not come across that. My google-foo has failed me!

Comment: @witnessmenow [DXSearch](http://search.devexpress.com) even better the google with DevExpresss))